# Setting a global variable, object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net-2010

I'm trying to get ID and Pass variables to be accessed by both Actions
but returns object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
Dim ID As String = txt1RegisterID.Text
Dim Pass As String = txt2RegisterPass.Text

Private Sub btn1Register_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1Register.Click
    If ID = "" And Pass = "" Then
        btn2Confirm.Enabled = False
        MessageBox.Show("Register user")
    Else
        txt1RegisterID.PasswordChar = " "
        txt2RegisterPass.PasswordChar = " "
        btn2Confirm.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btnConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn2Confirm.Click
    If txt3LoginID.Text = ID And txt4LoginPass.Text = Pass Then
        MessageBox.Show("Access Granted")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Access Denied")
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btn3Cancel_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn3Cancel.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You can't refer to the textboxes in that area of the form. Just initialize ID and Pass to the empty string, "", and set those variables to textbox values in a button's click event.

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering why it wouldn't work